# In SQL Server, what does it mean to be self-documenting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, self-documenting

I came across this term in a reading. Here is the context:

> "It is a best practice to make your T-SQL code self-documenting. Generally speaking, a view
>   will be more self-documenting if the column names of the view are specified in the SELECT
>   statement and not listed separately in the view."

I am just curious as to what this means. Any response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as any other piece of code.

Meaningful names:

- Give you table names that describe their contents.
- Give the columns names and types that describe their contents and are appropriate for them.
- Give your views, stored procedures, functions and other database objects descriptive names.

The specific quote seems to recommend using column names in views - I take this to mean that use of `SELECT *` is discouraged (it is a bad practice for various reasons).

Answer (score 2):

Specifically, the quote is saying:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
  SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM my_table
```

is better than:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view(col1,col2,col3) AS
  SELECT * FROM my_table
```

The quote is recommending two separate things:

1) Don't use the my_view(col1,col2,col3) syntax.  It's redundant, creates an additional maintenance burden, and provides a source for silent bugs (like swapped columns) if the order of the SELECT columns is changed but the view definition is not.

2) Don't use the * in any code you are saving.